# grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos7) error: unknown filesystem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, grubrescue

1. Recently I was trying to remove dual boot from my PC, I was using Linux as well as windows but later I wanted to use it as standalone Windows PC.
2. So I deleted the partition were my Linux system is present through windows disk management and tried to extend the volume but was not a successful attempt. In order to fix the grub bootloader I  should have restarted the PC by pressing the shift key twice but later I realized I didn't do the same. Then when I turned on the PC it was throwing grub rescue msg error.
3. After that I thought there might be some solution on internet for the issue, but those were basic ones, since in those you were able to find the windows boot manager and locate it.
4. But here in my case, I am not able to find any boot managers in any of my partition
   Also I tried with external bootable drive, there I found that my kernel is not working properly throwing BOSD error due to sudden power cut, the PC was shutdown during restart. [grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos7) error: unknown filesystem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UlA3.jpg)

Comment: If it was me I would be booting from a Ubuntu live media and using gparted to remove all partitions. Do not make any new ones. Boot from Windows install media and do an install as if it was a new hard drive.

Comment: **Note:** This might be a better question for Super User site. Before resorting to a full Windows reinstall I would try to install the Windows Boot Manager first. There are lots of instructions to do this. For example: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/rebuild-bcd-windows-10

Comment: Assuming Windows is still installed, and it sounds like it is, you need to fix its boot process as suggested above. Why would you expect grub to still work when you have deleted your Linux partition?

Comment: @PonJar I have Windows installed as you mentioned but as I mentioned I tried to delete the linux partition first and fix it by command prompt in the recovery mode

Comment: I would have thought it was obvious that by deleting your only Linux partition you would be deleting important parts of the grub boot software, but perhaps not.

Comment: @David an ubuntu image being flashed in USB or CD ?, also where can I find a gpart to do further steps that you mentioned, since I am amateur at these things, please do help me out....

Comment: @David Do I need to remove windows partition also via Ubuntu live media ??